# How to do pull to refresh in appium?

Tags: selenium, appium

I need add pull to refresh functionality and there is no elements found on the page. How to achieve this functionality. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You are right but i have tried and i wasn't getting any element on that page and not found any function by passing coordinate. Thanks

Comment: You need to post the code that you have tried and the resulting errors or describe what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

** You should always share the code you tried **

You can do a pull to refresh by swiping down from mid of screen to bottom of the screen. This way you don't have to be dependent on any Element. Following are the steps.

First get device height and width

```
int deviceWidth = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
int deviceHeight = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
```

calculate midX and midY

```
int midX = (deviceWidth / 2);
int midY = (deviceHeight / 2);
```

calculate bottom edge

```
int bottomEdge = (int) (deviceHeight * 0.85f);
```

You can perform a pull to refresh using TouchAction class

```
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(point(midX,midY))
    .waitAction(waitOptions(ofMillis(1000)))
    .moveTo(point(midX, bottomEdge))
    .release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void pullToRefresh(){

    int deviceWidth = driver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
    int deviceHeight = driver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();
    int midX = (deviceWidth / 2);
    int midY = (deviceHeight / 2);
    int bottomEdge = (int) (deviceHeight * 0.85f);
    new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(point(midX,midY))
            .waitAction(waitOptions(ofMillis(1000)))
            .moveTo(point(midX, bottomEdge))
            .release().perform();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).